# Idea tomcat run configuration cannot find xml files of spring

Tags: spring, servlets, intellij-idea, filenotfoundexception

I am using local tomcat server run configuration in idea. My code works just fine if I deploy it to the server through manager. However if I run it on idea it gives the following error :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]
```

I have this setting in web.xml :

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I have my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` folder. What could be causing this?

Comment: Where did you put the file mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml? should be `src / main / webapp / WEB-INF / mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`

Comment: It is exactly there. I should edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

Spring MVC looks for a file named [servlet-name]-servlet.xml in the WEB-INF directory of your web application and creates the beans defined there, overriding the definitions of any beans defined with the same name in the global scope.

[See this link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet)

The file name must be `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` and not `mvc-dispather-servlet.xml`.

Comment: I think it is pretty obvious that it was a typo.

Comment: Also I would like to add, the app works fine if I manually deploy it to the server, not using Idea's run config. This problem is about Idea, not my code.

Comment: Very often a typo are the first problem in this job :)